# What database catalogues citations in the humanities?

Tags: research-process, citations

Alright so I *know* what I'm thinking of exists, I just have absolutely no idea what it's called, and I'm driving myself crazy googling it. I'm looking for a resource that catalogs each instance a certain work is referenced in a certain time frame. For example, something that might show how many times, say, Moretti was referenced in academic journals and books in the past year. I've had professors mention this to me in passing, and I *think* I heard it was run by MLA, but I'm not sure. Something that could be used similarly to the h-index, but for the humanities.

What database catalogues citations and could be used to get a h-index in the humanities?

Comment: Do you mean Scopus?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of databases that may be of help.
The [Arts & Humanities Citation Index](http://thomsonreuters.com/en/products-services/scholarly-scientific-research/scholarly-search-and-discovery/arts-humanities-citation-index.html) by Thomson Reuters has access to over 1700 journals according to the following form their website.

> Arts & Humanities Citation Index®, accessed via Web of Science™ Core
>   Collection, provides researchers, administrators, faculty, and
>   students with quick, powerful access to the bibliographic and citation
>   information for journal articles in the arts & humanities that they
>   need to find research data, analyze trends, journals, and researchers,
>   and share their findings.
>
> Overcome information overload and focus on essential data from over
>   1,700 of the world's leading arts and humanities journals.

Also as mentioned in a comment there is [scopus](http://www.scopus.com) According to [this blog](http://www.researchtrends.com/issue-32-march-2013/towards-a-comprehensive-citation-index-for-the-arts-humanities/) scopus as of late 2012 has over 1 million articles from the arts and humanities.

> As of November 2012, the total number of Arts & Humanities articles in
>   the database is a little over 1 million, just over 2% of the total
>   database. All document types that are within the Scopus coverage
>   policy are included in the article counts. From 2007 to 2011 the
>   number of articles has grown from 42 thousand to 76 thousand articles
>   per year, which comes down to a compound annual growth rate (CAGR) of
>   16.2%

Both of them have fairly advanced search forms that should be able to do something like what you are looking for.